# How to compare 2 excel files using pandas and highlight the difference in each cell and save as excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 excel files

File 1

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
```

File 2

```
A B C D
1 3 3 4
5 6 9 8
9 1 2 3
3 6 7 8
```

I want the output as

Output

---

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **3** | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | **9** | 8 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| **3** | **6** | **7** | **8** |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` your input DataFrames, use a [styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html):

```
import numpy as np

def color(df, props=''):
    return np.where(df1.ne(df), props, '')

df2.style.apply(color, props='background-color:yellow', axis=None)
```

As an excel file:

```
(df2.style.apply(color, props='background-color:yellow', axis=None)
    .to_excel('out.xlsx')
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am getting error as NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: @Manu add `import numpy as np` in the beginning of your code

Comment: Thank you for above reply. Now I am trying to solve this error.                                     ValueError: Function <function color at 0x7f042df38af0> returned ndarray with wrong shape.